# pygame collisions with bullets cannot find collisions

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

When I run my code the program says to me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\two_player_gun_game.py", line 192, in <module>
    if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
NameError: name 'player_one_bullet' is not defined
```

I do not understand why this reason comes up I have created a function in one of the classes which is is_collided_with but. it still seems not to work can. I have put at the bottom an if statement which checks for collisions. colllisions are meant to be happening for player 1 and 2's bullets.
Here is my code to help:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption("this game")


class Background:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/images/space.jpg").convert()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (1280, 720))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_first:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/ezgif.com-crop.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (200, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))


class player_second:
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/Giantmechanicalcrab2 - Copy.gif")
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (300, 200))

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xpos = x
        self.ypos = y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x
        self.ypos += self.speed_y

    def draw(self):      #left right
        #screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, True, False), self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))







class player_one_Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/giphy.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos += self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


class player_two_Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    picture = pygame.image.load("C:/aliens/MajesticLavishBackswimmer-size_restricted.gif").convert_alpha()
    picture = pygame.transform.scale(picture, (100, 100))
    picture = pygame.transform.rotate(picture, 180)


    def __init__(self):
        self.xpos = 360
        self.ypos = 360
        self.speed_x = 0
        super().__init__()
        self.rect = self.picture.get_rect()


    def update(self):
        self.xpos -= self.speed_x

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.picture, (self.xpos, self.ypos))
        #self.screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(self.picture, False, True), self.rect)

    def is_collided_with(self, sprite):
        return self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect)


player_one = player_first(0, 0)
player_two = player_second(1000, 0)
cliff = Background(0, 0)
player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_two_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()



while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player_one.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player_one.speed_y = 5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player_two.speed_y = -5

                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player_two.speed_y = 5







                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    player_one_bullet = player_one_Bullet()

                    player_one_bullet.ypos = player_one.ypos
                    player_one_bullet.xpos = player_one.xpos

                    player_one_bullet.speed_x = 14

                    player_one_bullet_list.add(player_one_bullet)



                elif event.key == pygame.K_KP0:
                    player_two_bullet = player_two_Bullet()

                    player_two_bullet.ypos = player_two.ypos
                    player_two_bullet.xpos = player_two.xpos

                    player_two_bullet.speed_x = 14

                    player_two_bullet_list.add(player_two_bullet)




            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                # Stop moving when the keys are released.
                if event.key == pygame.K_s and player_one.speed_y > 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w and player_one.speed_y < 0:
                    player_one.speed_y = 0


                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player_two.speed_y > 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and player_two.speed_y < 0:
                    player_two.speed_y = 0


    if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):  
            player_one_bullet.kill()


    if player_two_bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):  
            player_two_bullet.kill()

    player_one.update()
    player_two.update()
    cliff.draw()
    player_one.draw()
    player_two.draw()

    player_one_bullet_list.update()
    player_two_bullet_list.update()

    for player_one_bullet in player_one_bullet_list:
            player_one_bullet.draw()


    for player_two_bullet in player_two_bullet_list:
            player_two_bullet.draw()



    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)



#IGNORE THIS 
#player_one_bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()



#elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
#                    player_one_bullet = player_one_Bullet()
#
#                    player_one_bullet.ypos = player_one.ypos
#                    player_one.xpos = player_one.xpos
#
#                    player_one_bullet.speed_x = 14
#
#                    player_one_bullet_list.add(player_one_bullet)
#
#    
#player_one_bullet_list.update()
#
#    for player_one_bullet in player_one_bullet_list:
#            player_one_bullet.draw()


#if hammerhood.rect.colliderect(crab):  #.rect.top
#            hammerhood.speed_y = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When python complains about something not being defined, it typically means you are trying to use something which is not there or has not yet been made.

This is the only time you define 'player_one_bullet':

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    player_one_bullet = player_one_Bullet()`
```

So long as you do not press space, there are no bullets and 'player_one_bullet' remains undefined.

That is the reason why this piece of code gives an error:

```
if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
```

You cannot use something which does not exist!

Additionally only the last bullet fired from each player will check if it is hitting the other player, the other bullets will ignore everything!

Fortunately there is an easy way to fix it; instead of doing this:

```
if player_one_bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):  
    player_one_bullet.kill()

if player_two_bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):  
    player_two_bullet.kill()
```

You can use `player_one_bullet_list` and `player_two_bullet_list` to check if bullets exist and whether they are colliding!

```
for bullet in player_one_bullet_list.sprites():
    if bullet.is_collided_with(player_two):
        player_one_bullet.kill()

for bullet in player_two_bullet_list.sprites():
    if bullet.is_collided_with(player_one):
        player_two_bullet.kill()
```

Now you have a for loop that iterates through the list of bullets and if any exist only then it checks whether there is a collision.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: this did not work and now instead the bullets come onto the screen and suddenly disappear